# VBA 'For Each' Selected Items

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

I would like to loop through the *selected* items in a PageField. I can loop through every data item (in my case, alphabet letter) using the following code:

```
Dim PT As PivotTable
Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Dim Letter As PivotItem

For Each Letter In PT.PivotFields("Alphabet").PivotItems

'Code for each letter of the alphabet

Next Letter
```

However if I have only selected several non-continuous dynamic letters (A,J,P,S,X) in the PageField, how do I restrict the loop to these letters?

Comment: Simply `If Letter.Visible then`

Comment: The Letters will be limited to those values in the PivotFields "Letter"  So provided your list is only AJPSX to begin with, it should only loop though those letters.

Comment: Can you please elaborate @Rory? I have amended the code to the following, with no success: If Letter.Visible Then For Each Letter in PT.PivotFields("Alphabet").PivotItems MsgBox Letter.Name Next Letter End If

Comment: That is true @xQbert, however in this case the list is the full alphabet A-Z and it is only that some letters are selected in the current filter (PageField) and some aren't. I want to loop through only the selected letters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like so:

```
Dim PT As PivotTable
Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Dim Letter As PivotItem

For Each Letter In PT.PivotFields("Alphabet").PivotItems
   if letter.visible then
'Code for each letter of the alphabet
   end if
Next Letter
```